# Get ActivityId From SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, activities, singleemailmessage

When sending a SingleEmailMessage from apex to a Contact, activities are automatically created for that Contact. I also want to log an activity on records that are related to this email. I can't use a WhatId because the email would be related to several different records. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });

Task contactActivity = [ SELECT Subject FROM Task WHERE Id = :contactActivityId ]; 
List<Task> relatedRecordActivities = new List<Task>();
for( My_Object__c object : objects )
{
    Task relatedTask = contactActivtiy.clone();
    relatedTask.WhatId = object.Id;
    relatedRecordActivities.add( relatedTask );
}
insert relatedRecordActivities;
```

I'm not sure how to to get the contactActivityId. I could just use the subject and the created date to help query for the activity based on the contact, but is there a more direct approach?

Comment: First question to ask yourself is whether the Contact's Task  is even available to you in the same transaction.  You can ascertain this by using execute anonymous that sends the email and then queries the Contact's task. If it is available, then the soql/dml approach as outlined above will work. If not, you'll need to use an @future method to do the soql + dml

Answer (score 0):

When the email is sent, a Task is created.
When the Task is created, you want to clone it and link to other objects.
You could do this with a trigger on the Task if you can identify, from the Task alone

- which Tasks are the sort of email you need to clone (do they have a set subject line?)
- which are the other objects you need to link the clones to (can they be worked out by looking at, for instance, the Task's Contact?)